# Appcelerator Titanium and Apple Pay

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, applepay

I am trying to use Apple Pay in a Titanium app. So far I've gotten it to work about a third of the time I run the app, the rest of the time the app crashes. My suspicion is that not adding the apple pay entitlement to the app is causing the crash (unfortunately there is no error message in the console when the app crashes).

Has anyone had any luck getting Apple Pay to work in a Titanium app?

Comment: Which module you used for Apple Pay in Titanium?

Comment: I ended up writing my own module.

Comment: Is yours module available for reuse by others ?

Comment: It isn't, but you can get most of what you need from the gist I posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working. Here is a gist of the code in my module: https://gist.github.com/zach-babb-moovel/bd4172454cf54a178855e76ca5dd1f48. The key was wrapping the PKPaymentRequest and subsequent PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController parts in a dispatch_async call. You'll also have to make sure all your profiles are set up correctly and that you use a custom Entitlements.plist file for your Titanium project. Check out the Entitlements.plist here: https://github.com/hansemannn/applepaydemo/blob/master/Entitlements.plist for what it should look like.

Answer (score 1):

Well, without advertising my [Ti.ApplePay module](https://marketplace.appcelerator.com/apps/68814), this might be the easiest way to adopt Apple Pay with Titanium. It supports all major Titanium versions and includes all native API's that are available. Give it a try or use a custom one :-)